# how to build database structure of language translation system

Tags: mysql

how to build database structure of language translation system?
hello friends..
here i am little confuse ...with this application..
give me a best way to define a database structure of language translation system...

waiting for you reply

Comment: Might need a few more infos on this topic...

Comment: It depends on your approach: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_translation#Approaches

Comment: The approach taken by `gettext` could give you some hints: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Overview

Comment: Give us your thoughts, something to work off of.  Without anything to look at, it sounds more like you are asking us to do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SourceLanguage id
SourceLanguage meaning id
destination language id
destination meaning id

and create different table for language and its meaning

Answer (score 0):

A simple structure would be to have a dictionary approach i.e., A table with following columns:

```
SourceLanguage
SourceWord
TargetLanguage
TargetWord
```

Comment: hi faisal...thanx...now i can start next step.........thanQ very much..

Comment: yaa that iknow but..can i do it in different way..???